# Discussion about convergence of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

If {sn} and {sn + tn} are both convergent then so is {tn}. is this statement correct by the sum of limit of sequence which says Suppose that the sequences {sn} and {tn} are convergent. Then
lim
n→∞
(sn + tn) = lim
n→∞
sn + lim
n→∞
tn.
If this a correct way to solve this problem? If this is wrong statement then what can we have as a counterexample because I wasn't able to find a counterexample  for this statement. Thanks in advance

Comment: $\lim t_n =\lim [(s_n+t_n)-s_n]=\lim [(s_n+t_n)] -\lim s_n$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write maths.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.